# Send Flash Player to background or place div on top of Flash Player

Tags: html, flash

I am aware that Flash Player is actualy browser plugin finaly rendered on top of html page, however I hope there is a way to somehow send flash player to background or place div on top of flash.

In this sample code I would like "divPanel" to be displayed over the "flashHeader".

```
<object id="flashHeader" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index:3;" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
    codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0"
    width="820" height="255" id="Untitled-1" align="middle">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="movie" value="my.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <embed src="my.swf"
        quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="820" height="255" name="Untitled-1" align="middle"
        allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
<div id="divPanel" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red; position: relative;
    top: -50; z-index:4;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change de param `wmode` to "Opaque". [More info](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_)

Comment: I looks like I had a problem with browser cache. Clearing cache and setting this line did the job:

<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />

Thanks! :)